# Add user defined object as key in hashmap

Tags: java, object, arraylist, hashmap

```
public class Dashboard {
int REQUEST_ID, PRICE;           
String LOGIN_USER;

public int getREQUEST_ID() {
 return REQUEST_ID;
}

public void setREQUEST_ID(int rEQUEST_ID) {
 REQUEST_ID = rEQUEST_ID;
 }

 //all getters and setters
public class DBConnection {
public ArrayList<Dashboard>  getStoreResult() {
  ArrayList<Dashboard> dashRec=new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
  Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();

try{
  Class.forName("");
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("");
  Statement st=con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("");

  HashMap<Object, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
  while (rs.next()) {
    Integer id = rs.getInt(1);
    if (!map.containsKey(id)) {
        dashRec= new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
        map.put(id, dashRec);
    }
    dash = new Dashboard();
    dash.setREQUEST_ID(id);
    dash.setLOGIN_USER(rs.getString(2));
    dash.setPRICE(rs.getInt(3));
    map.get(id).add(dash);
     } 
    }
```

I want to add name and Reqid for each set of row as key object in map.So for like id 123 I need a map with id=123,Name=A as key.The value would be arraylist which contains all rows specific to id.For id=123,arraylist contains first 3 rows as 3 objects.I want to add the id 123 and name as key now for all sets of row.

[image: SQL DB]

Comment: you want a composite key(id+name) as mapKey ?

Comment: @CodeScale yes I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can materialize your key as a specific type.

```java
public class MapKey {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;

  MapKey(Integer id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    MapKey mapKey = (MapKey) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, mapKey.id) &&
            Objects.equals(name, mapKey.name);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, name);
  }
}
```

and then use this object as key of your map.

`map.put(new MapKey("", 0), new Dash...);`

ps: don't forget most important parts --> override correctly `equals` and `hashcode` in `MapKey`

Extraction:

```java
MapKey key = new MapKey(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
    dashRec= new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
    map.put(key, dashRec);
}
```

Comment: As I am newbie to java, can you show me how the above code works in the code I provided?

Comment: the "name" is extracted from the resultset ?

Comment: ya it is extracted

Comment: So public class MapKey is a another class which I need to create.Bcoz I have one class Dashboard which has getter and setters for each attribute.

Comment: as you want a composite key for your hashmap You can use  MapKey type (ID + NAME).  You construct this key based on the resultset `new MapKey(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2))` What is not clear ?

Comment: override equals and hashcode...what and why need to be done?

Comment: to be sure that the same key : example (123, A) is not used twice in the same map. And also to verify if key already exists (contains) and recover your list of dash.

Comment: Can you insert the code or let me know the logic for public boolean equals(Object equals) and  public int hashCode()

Comment: I have a small requirement. There is a change in the picture attached in the question.Actually I want is KEY  to contain lowest status no of a specific set.Here set refers to number of rows of a particular ReqId. For e.g.:For reqid 123,we have 7rows constituting as a set. The lowest status no is 1 which I need as value.Similarly, for key 456,I need value 2.So key must have reqid, name and lowest status no.I actually have created a second map to do so.But I need it in same map.The logic for the same is:

Comment: Map<Integer, Integer> mapStatus = new HashMap<>();                                                              
while (rs.next()) {
    ... // your existing codes
    if (!mapStatus.containsKey(id) || mapStatus.get(id)>dash.getStatus()) {
        mapStatus.put(id, dash.getStatus());
    } 
}

Comment: Can you make changes in class mapkey if possible?

Comment: Can you plz answer this question?Its related to your answer over here. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61851846/getting-last-rows-data-in-the-map

Answer (score 1):

try this for unique ness

```
public class Dashboard {
int REQUEST_ID, PRICE;           
String LOGIN_USER;

public int getREQUEST_ID() {
 return REQUEST_ID;
}

public void setREQUEST_ID(int rEQUEST_ID) {
 REQUEST_ID = rEQUEST_ID;
 }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Dashboard dash = (Dashboard) o;
    return Objects.equals(REQUEST_ID, dash.REQUEST_ID) && Objects.equals(LOGIN_USER, dash.LOGIN_USER) && && Objects.equals(PRICE, dash.PRICE);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(REQUEST_ID, PRICE+","+LOGIN_USER
    );
  }


 }
```

Comment: What changes must be done in DBConnection class then?

Comment: Can you please tell me what changes must be done in DBConnection class ??

Answer (score 0):

@Aziz

try this

```
 //all getters and setters
public class DBConnection {
public ArrayList<Dashboard>  getStoreResult() {
  ArrayList<Dashboard> dashRec=new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
  Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();

try{
  Class.forName("");
  Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("");
  Statement st=con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("");

  HashMap<Object, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();

while (rs.next()) {

     Integer id = rs.getInt(1);
    Set<Dashboard> keysets = map.keySet();
    Dashboard d = null;
    for (Dashboard dash : keysets) {
        if(dash.getREQUEST_ID().equals.(id)){
            d = dash;
            break;
        }
    }

    Dashboard dash1 = new Dashboard();
    dash1.setREQUEST_ID(id);
    dash1.setLOGIN_USER(rs.getString(2));
    dash1.setPRICE(rs.getInt(3));

    if(d!=null){
        map.get(d).add(dash1)
    }else{
        List<Dashboard> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        lst.add(dash1);
        map.put(dash1,lst)
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, per your requirement, I am using Dashborad as key, each time you get rs.next , I check object is already in key set , if yes . then i simple add the object in associated list, if not just create a new list to add

Comment: ohk got it. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you plz answer this question?Its related to your answer over here. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61851846/getting-last-rows-data-in-the-map