# Getting last row's data in the map

Tags: java, object, arraylist, collections, hashmap

My objective is to create a map.

It have `reqid`,`name` and lowest `status` number of a set as a key.

Here set refers to rows belonging to a specific `Reqid`.

The value of the map is an *Arraylist* which consists of all rows as objects of a specific `id`.

```
public class MapKey {
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private Integer status;

   public MapKey(Integer id, String name,Integer status) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.status=status;
  }
   @Override toString,hashCode,equals
  public class Dashboard {
  int REQUEST_ID; 
  String name;
  int price;
  int status;
  public int getREQUEST_ID() {
    return REQUEST_ID;
 }
 public void setREQUEST_ID(int rEQUEST_ID) {
    REQUEST_ID = rEQUEST_ID;
 }
 //getters and setters



 public class DBConnection {
public ArrayList<Dashboard>  getStoreResult() {
    ArrayList<Dashboard> dashRec=new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
    Dashboard dash = new Dashboard();

    try{
        Class.forName("");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("");
        HashMap<Object, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
        int status=100;
        int reqid=0;
        String name1=null;
        while (rs.next()) {
            Integer id = rs.getInt(1);
            String name=rs.getString(2);
            if(reqid==0) {
                reqid=id;   
                name1=name;
            }
            if(reqid !=id) {
                MapKey key = new MapKey(reqid,name1,status);
                map.put(key, dashRec);
                reqid=id;
                name1=name;
                dashRec= new ArrayList<Dashboard>();
                status=100;
            }

            dash = new Dashboard();
            dash.setREQUEST_ID(id);
            dash.setLOGIN_USER(name);
            dash.setPRICE(rs.getInt(3));
            dash.setSTATUS(rs.getInt(4));
            dashRec.add(dash);
            if(rs.getInt(4)<=status) {
                status=rs.getInt(4);
            }
        }
```

The output is like:

```
MapKey [reqid=123, name=A,status=1]:[Dashboard [reqid=123, NAME=A, 
PRICE=5,STATUS=2],Dashboard [reqid=123, NAME=A, PRICE=10,STATUS=3],...,..]
```

It captures data only till `reqid` 456, However my code cant capture last unique `reqid` row data in the map.

SQL Database:

[image]

Comment: "It have reqid,name and lowest status number of a set as a key." so the unique key is actually only the reqid and name?

Comment: No the key is  MapKey [reqid=123, name=A,status=1] which has unique name and reqid and lowest status no of that set

Comment: I just want last set to be inserted in map.All data till last set is being inserted successfully.

Comment: have u try to debug it?

Comment: Code works fine till reqid 456. After that values get stored in dashrec arraylist but it isnt inserted in map.I just want that logic how to handle last set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
        Map<MapKey, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int reqId = rs.getInt(1);
            String name = rs.getString(2);
            int price = rs.getInt(3);
            int status = rs.getInt(4);

            //iterate map look for existing data
            boolean exist = false;
            for (Map.Entry<MapKey, List<Dashboard>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                MapKey mapKey = entry.getKey();
                List<Dashboard> dashboards = entry.getValue();
                if (mapKey.getId()==reqId && mapKey.getName().equals(name)) {
                    exist = true;
                    //check for status and update it if lower than existing status
                    if (status < mapKey.getStatus())
                        mapKey.setStatus(status);

                    //add dashboard
                    Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
                    dashboard.setREQUEST_ID(reqId);
                    dashboard.setName(name);
                    dashboard.setPrice(price);
                    dashboard.setStatus(status);
                    dashboards.add(dashboard);
                }
            }
            if (!exist) {
                MapKey mapKey = new MapKey(reqId, name, status);

                Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
                dashboard.setREQUEST_ID(reqId);
                dashboard.setName(name);
                dashboard.setPrice(price);
                dashboard.setStatus(status);
                List<Dashboard> dashboards = new ArrayList<>();
                dashboards.add(dashboard);

                map.put(mapKey, dashboards);
            }
        }
```

Update: 2nd answer if cannot set values to MapKey

```
        Map<Map<String, Object>, List<Dashboard>> map = new HashMap<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            int reqId = rs.getInt(1);
            String name = rs.getString(2);
            int price = rs.getInt(3);
            int status = rs.getInt(4);

            //iterate map look for existing data
            boolean exist = false;
            for (Map.Entry<Map<String, Object>, List<Dashboard>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                Map<String,Object> mapKey = entry.getKey();
                List<Dashboard> dashboards = entry.getValue();
                if (mapKey.get("id").toString().equals(reqId) && mapKey.get("name").toString().equals(name)) {
                    exist = true;
                    //check for status and update it if lower than existing status
                    if (status < Integer.valueOf(mapKey.get("status").toString()))
                        mapKey.put("status", status);

                    //add dashboard
                    Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
                    dashboard.setREQUEST_ID(reqId);
                    dashboard.setName(name);
                    dashboard.setPrice(price);
                    dashboard.setStatus(status);
                    dashboards.add(dashboard);
                }
            }
            if (!exist) {
                Map<String,Object> mapKey = new HashMap<>();
                mapKey.put("id", reqId);
                mapKey.put("name", name);
                mapKey.put("status", status);

                Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard();
                dashboard.setREQUEST_ID(reqId);
                dashboard.setName(name);
                dashboard.setPrice(price);
                dashboard.setStatus(status);
                List<Dashboard> dashboards = new ArrayList<>();
                dashboards.add(dashboard);

                map.put(mapKey, dashboards);
            }
        }
        Map<MapKey, List<Dashboard>> map0 = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Map<String, Object>, List<Dashboard>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Map<String,Object> mapKey = entry.getKey();
            List<Dashboard> dashboards = entry.getValue();
            MapKey mapKey0 = new MapKey(
                Integer.valueOf(mapKey.get("id").toString()), 
                mapKey.get("name").toString(), 
                Integer.valueOf(mapKey.get("status").toString()));
                map0.put(mapKey0, dashboards);
        }
```

Comment: I have already initialized reqId and status before while loop.So do I need to keep them or directly initialized in while loop?

Comment: why you initialized them before while loop? seem to me it is hardcoded? I prefer my way if you don't really have to initialized them before the loop, what for?

Comment: The method getId() is undefined for the type MapKey ,The method getName() is undefined for the type MapKey,The method getStatus() is undefined for the type MapKey,The method setStatus(int) is undefined for the type MapKey is the error at line 11,12,14.

Comment: bcoz mapkey doesnt have getId,getName, functions..It has just a constructor

Comment: you have to give access to put value to the id, name status.

Comment: ya but getId,getId,getName functions are defined in dashboard class

Comment: we can get values from dashboard class

Comment: Thanks bro.It works fine.But can you plz explain me the code. I am not getting it.

Comment: the for loop part

Comment: but u said it was wrong. If u can only get values from dashboard class then the solution I have is to use HashMap as the key and then after iterate/loop to set what u want, u need to iterate again using MapKey as the key. u want me to update the answer?

Comment: I didnt get you.You have created a map which has Mapkey object as a key and arraylist as value

Comment: It is working fine.I have created getters and setters of Mapkey class.So now I can give access to  put value to the id, name status

Comment: I create 2 map which first is Map<Map<String,Object>, List<Dashboard>> where Map<String,Object> to replace the MapKey because MapKey only has constructor and cannot set values. Then I loop it like my answer. After the loop then I loop the map again to create new map Map<MapKey, List<Dashboard>> to create MapKey based on Map<String,Object> values in the first loop

Comment: If u can create getters and setters of MapKey then it's good because it's only need one loop. so which 'for loop' part u don't understand? It is basically looping the map that used to put the values, check the key if it contains reqid and name then get the value(the list) then add result to the list, then it also check the status if status from result is lower then update the status in the key. after the loop if no key found in the map then it create new values as new key and new list

Comment: But where have you created another map?The first one is created on line 1.

Comment: I have added 2nd answer

Comment: For me,the 1st one works fine.Thanks again for your help and time.

Comment: One small doubt,when I run map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ":" + value)); complete map is printed in console.But when I run map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(map.get(value))); it gives me null as value.Why is it so?

Comment: because u want to get the value in the map using value as the key. should be map.get(key).

Comment: When I run map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(map.get(key))); it prints the arraylist of first key.For remaining keys,it print null.How to rectify the error?

Comment: not happening to me. the right way using forEach is using the value variable, if u want to get the value

Comment: Do you mean I print map.get(value)

Comment: I mean this -> "when I run map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ":" + value)); complete map is printed in console".